# gather() function in R - combination of wide to long/long to wide

Tags: r

I just recently started learning R and I ran into an issue when trying to use the gather function.
I want to transform the data table into the following, but i have problems with the combination of rows into columns and columns into rows

Original:

[image: original data set]

Transformed:

[image: transformed data set]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Note that `gather` has been deprecated in favour of `pivot_longer`. Also, please don’t post code, error messages or data as images. It makes life harder for those who might help you and breaks text readers and hinders future searches by those with a similar problem.

Comment: You want a combo of `gather` + `spread`. But as you started it would be wise and is recommended (see `?tidyr::gather`) to learn and use `pivot_longer` = gather and `pivot_wider` = spread. Both `gather` and `spread` are superseded and both `pivot_` functions are more powerful.

Answer (score 0):

please try the below code

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% pivot_longer(cols = -c(Figure ,Country, Material), names_to = 'date')  %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(Country, Material, date), names_from = Figure, values_from =  value)


# A tibble: 12 × 6
   Country Material date  Actual Forecast Forecast2
   <chr>   <chr>    <chr> <chr>  <chr>    <chr>    
 1 Poland  A        Jan   0      6        6        
 2 Poland  A        Feb   0      8        8        
 3 Poland  A        Mrz   0      3        3        
 4 Poland  A        Apr   20     3        3        
 5 Poland  A        Mai   20     4        4        
 6 Poland  A        Jun   <NA>   <NA>     <NA>     
 7 Poland  A        Jul   0      4        4        
 8 Poland  A        Aug   41     6        6        
 9 Poland  A        Sep   0      5        5        
10 Poland  A        Okt   0      5        5        
11 Poland  A        Nov   0      10       10       
12 Poland  A        Dez   0      7        7
```